# Date input field formatting problem in channel form

Tags: channel-entries, channel-form, date

**# Goal**

Display multiple entries using `{exp:channel:entries}` and within each entry use a `{exp:channel:form}` to allow editing the entry’s content.

**# Problem**

Using this method, I’m able to display and edit entry select fields and checkboxes but a custom field using the native date type does not work.

For example, if an entry’s custom date field contains the value 2013-11-29 12:00 AM, the corresponding date input field in my channel form has the value: ‘1385704800’

Additionally, clicking the date input field does not display the date picker.

This problem only arises when a channel form is wrapped in a channel entries tag. Creating a new entry with the channel form by itself works fine.

I’m running 2.7.2.

**Edit:** Here's the simplified template code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="projects" disable="pagination|categories|member_data" status="Open"}
    {exp:channel:form channel="projects" return="graphics/manager" entry_id="{entry_id}" json="yes" id="publishForm{entry_id}" include_jquery="no" preserve_checkboxes="yes" disable="categories|member_data"}
        {cf-form-proj-due format='%M. %d'} <!-- This works -->
        <input type="text" name="cf-form-proj-due" id="cf-form-proj-due" value="{cf-form-proj-due}"> <!-- This does not work -->
    {/exp:channel:form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: can you publish your template code?

Comment: I've added the simplified template code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what might be happening is that the JavaScript for the datepicker is being added to the page multiple times, by each loop through the channel entries tag.

There is a parameter for the channel form tag `include_assets="no"` which will prevent it from adding the Javascript, so perhaps you could use that with a conditional to only output the assets on the first entry. Adjust your code like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="projects" disable="pagination|categories|member_data" status="Open"}
    {exp:channel:form channel="projects" return="graphics/manager" entry_id="{entry_id}" json="yes" id="publishForm{entry_id}" include_jquery="no" preserve_checkboxes="yes" disable="categories|member_data" {if count > 1}include_assets="no"{/if} }
        {cf-form-proj-due format='%M. %d'} <!-- This works -->
        <input type="text" name="cf-form-proj-due" id="cf-form-proj-due" value="{cf-form-proj-due}"> <!-- This does not work -->
    {/exp:channel:form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the behavior remains the same. I also tried adding `include_assets="no"` without any conditional, and it removed the calendar icon from the input as expected, but the string of numbers remained.

Comment: The string of numbers is a unix timestamp. There's nothing wrong with that. If you attached your own jQuery UI datepicker script to the field it should be able to pick that up and convert it.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I might end up having to do that, though, that would only seem to fix the problem after you click the date input field. The UNIX timestamp would still be visible at the beginning unless you used more jQuery to reformat it.

Comment: I can't imagine it would be there for long, unless you're on a really slow host.

Comment: But, you could also format it. The datepicker shouldn't care.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Jeremy. I did as you suggested, using jQuery, and all works well. The original problem perhaps is an EE bug or I'm incorrectly using the channel form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datepicker = "no" in your exp:channel:form tag and add a jquery:

```
$('#start_date').datepicker({changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, yearRange:'today.getFullYear():2020',dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'});
```